# Save image from bitmap in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm showing images from server in Viewpager with Glide. I have a button where user can save current image on clicking it.

```
// Code from FullImage Fragment
save_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(myViewPagerAdapter.getBitmap() != null)
                saveImage(myViewPagerAdapter.getBitmap());

            }
        });
```

I'm getting bitmap from ViewpagerAdapter like this -

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
Bitmap bitmap;
private ArrayList<Object> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> images) {
    context = this.context;
    this.imagesList = images;
}

@NonNull
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object recyclerViewItem = imagesList.get(position);
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.util_image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);
    final TouchImageView imageViewPreview = view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(view.getContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (recyclerViewItem instanceof Advertiser) {
        Advertiser advertiser = (Advertiser) imagesList.get(position);
        GlideApp
                .with(container.getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(advertiser.getUrl())
                .fitCenter().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        imageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }


                });
        ;
    } else {
        Photos image = (Photos) imagesList.get(position);
        GlideApp
                .with(container.getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(image.getUrl())

                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        bitmap = resource;
                        imageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }


                });

    }
    container.addView(view);
    return view;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imagesList.size();

}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
    return view.equals(obj);
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

public interface OnClickListener {

    void performClick();
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

My problem is that this code working but It's saving next image from viewpager(I know that viewpager load 3 images, next, current and previous).
Now how can i get the current bitmap ?

Comment: Could you post all code of your ViewPager?

Comment: @Aolphn Edited the question.

Comment: I post my answer,please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a variable mMap which type is `SparseArray<Bitmap>` for your ViewPager put bitmap after bitmap load completely
2. Add a variable mCurrentPosition for your ViewPager and set its value in method instantiateItem
3. change getBitmap's logic like following code snippet

// replace your getBitmap by following code

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(int pos){

   return mMap.get(pos);

}
```

redit:about how to declear a variable mMap and initialize it.

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    ...
    Context context;
    SparseArray<Bitmap> mMap = new SparseArray<Bitmap>();
    ...
}


public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ...
    //add your bitmap in here after it load complete
    mMap.put(position,bitmap)
    ...
}
```

reedit: in saveImage should be following:

```
saveImage(myViewPagerAdapter.getBitmap(position));
```

Comment: I reedit my answer,please check it ,you can comment here if you got any question .

Comment: instantiateItem 's params position

Comment: Could you change it to mMap.get(mCurrentPosition) and try again?